# Crossed effects without all combinations

Tags: regression, mixed-model, nested-data, nested-models, crossed-random-effects

There are a number of posts on Cross Validated explaining the difference between nested and crossed random-effects. In [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/400700/why-do-we-do-crossed-vs-nested-vs-other-random-effects) example, it is noted that all feasible random effects categories are linked to all other random effects categories, i.e. **"all participants perform all tasks."**

In [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified) example, the same is noted: **"which means that every class belongs to every school."**

However, what happens when there is no specific nested structure, but there are some instances where some categories are not linked with others. Example:

Let's say I'm conducting field work and I visit around 5 sites per year of a possible 10 sites, call them Sites 1-10. The number of sites does not vary, but the exact sites selected for sampling do. This study is ongoing and there are 5 years of data. The code below generates some artificial data of that design using `r`:

```r
sites = c(1:10)
years = c(1:5)
set.seed(1)
for(i in unique(years)){
if(i==1){
  df = data.frame(year = rep(i,5),
                  site = sample(x = sites,
                                size = 5,
                                replace = F),
                  visit = c(1:5))}
  if(i>1){
    df2 = data.frame(year = rep(i,5),
                     site = sample(x = sites,
                                   size = 5,
                                   replace = F),
                     visit = c(1:5))
    df = rbind(df2,df)}}
```

The data:

```
df
#>    year site visit
#> 1     5    5     1
#> 2     5    9     2
#> 3     5    1     3
#> 4     5    6     4
#> 5     5   10     5
#> 6     4   10     1
#> 7     4    7     2
#> 8     4    1     3
#> 9     4    9     4
#> 10    4    5     5
#> 11    3    5     1
#> 12    3   10     2
#> 13    3    2     3
#> 14    3    6     4
#> 15    3    7     5
#> 16    2    7     1
#> 17    2    2     2
#> 18    2    3     3
#> 19    2    8     4
#> 20    2    1     5
#> 21    1    9     1
#> 22    1    4     2
#> 23    1    7     3
#> 24    1    1     4
#> 25    1    2     5
```

Where the combinations of sites and year are as follows:

Site visit frequency:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  summarize(tot = n())
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>     site   tot
#>    <int> <int>
#>  1     1     4
#>  2     2     3
#>  3     3     1
#>  4     4     1
#>  5     5     3
#>  6     6     2
#>  7     7     4
#>  8     8     1
#>  9     9     3
#> 10    10     3
```

Yearly sampling frequency:

```
df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(tot=n())
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>    year   tot
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     5
#> 2     2     5
#> 3     3     5
#> 4     4     5
#> 5     5     5
```

Frequency of combinations:

```
df %>%
  group_by(site,year) %>%
  summarize(tot=n())
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'site'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 25 × 3
#> # Groups:   site [10]
#>     site  year   tot
#>    <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1     1     1
#>  2     1     2     1
#>  3     1     4     1
#>  4     1     5     1
#>  5     2     1     1
#>  6     2     2     1
#>  7     2     3     1
#>  8     3     2     1
#>  9     4     1     1
#> 10     5     3     1
#> # … with 15 more rows
```

We see that all years occur and all sites occur, but not all combinations of year and sites occur.

Does such a design count as a crossed design, even though some combinations of sites and years do not occur? If not, what is the name of such a design?